# Interoperability between Ethereum's Public Blockchain and Quorum's Private Permissioned Blokchain Network

Tags: private-blockchain, quorum, permissioned-chain, blockchain-interoperation

**Scenario:**
I am trying to set two blockchain networks on a platform:

- Ethereum's Public Blockchain Network: For payment system in the form of ERC20 Tokens and Cryptocurrencies.
- Quorum's Private Permissioned Blockchain Network: For Data Storage and Permissioned access.

**Questions:**

- Can I make the two different blockchain networks(mentioned above) talk to each other? Are there any issues involved? How can I do that?
- Are Quorum and Ethereum compatible? Or should I choose another blockchain?
- For Enterprise level application Is Quorum scalable and API rich?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, No. `Quorum` and `ethereum` are not interoperable. A simple argument will be the consensus algorithm used by these two : quorum uses `RAFT` and `ethereum` uses the proof of work. Also, `quorum`uses extra cryptography tools in order to privatize the viewing of transactions between parties, which is contradictory with `ethereum`.

Making them tag to each other can be done via a third tool, mainly a client for both blockchain at the same time, that would be able to use the data received from one in order to interact with the second blockchain (though it is not really a practical idea, from the point of the usefulness).

The scalability of `quorum` is not really an issue, because a private blockchain is rather not really meant to be used on a large scale(1000+ nodes). but it can go to lengths similar to `ethereum`.

Comment: thanks for your response. In order to make both the blockchain talk I am thinking to write a seperate nodejs/angular/js code which will push and retrieve data.

Comment: from your answer I got that Ethereum and Quorum are not interoperable but they can talk to each other via third tool. As we know Ethereum is very mature due to it's API availability from development perspective. Is it the same case with Quorum, is quorum API rich for development?

Comment: @Saumitra quorum, is just a fork of the `geth` ethereum client. It has the exact same capabilities as a regular ethereum client, that includes smart contract RPC API.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot] According to a whitepaper of bitcoin [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) privacy is maintained by not disclosing the identity of the participant. Two people can transact with each other without knowing their identities. However, in private permissioned blockchain network every participant needs to disclose their identity. If two participant in Quorum's private permissioned blockchain network wants to transact with each other using ethereum's public ethereum blockchain network then every participant in Quorum's private ethereum blockchain network will know public ethereum account history of all the participants in quorum's private permissioned blockchain network because of that **privacy** of participants Quorum's private permissioned network will be **compromised**.

Comment: I may not have explained my self clearly. Privacy of Data storage on Private Permissioned Blockchain is the focus of my use case. Anyone who joins the private permissioned network is already trusted and known to other participants of the network, so no need for the identity privacy within the network. 
My question here is, if two participants share the data within private permissioned network, then how one will incentivize(via token/crypto) the other on public network? Use of Public Network is necessary because i want transparency in payment system. So, how these two networks will talk?

Comment: Also if anyone can help me understand the Scalability and API availability in Quorum while working with Ethereum. Can Quorum be used along with Ethereum in one platform?

Comment: Hi @Saumitra, The consensus algorithm to incentivize participant is Proof Of Work which is used in public ethereum blockchain network and Consensus algorithms used by Quorum are
QuorumChain Consensus, Raft Consensus, and Istanbul consensus. Consensus algorithms used in quorum are purely based on voting and does not involve mining at all. Mining is the process of solving a cryptographic puzzle to verify transactions and the node who solves that puzzle gets rewards. This is the heart of Proof Of Work consensus algorithm.

Comment: @Saumitra did you find the answer? if yes, please share.